# React js Uncaught TypeError ReactFireMixin error

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a simple application, right now trying to integrate Firebase, but I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ReactFireMixin' of undefined

(anonymous function)    @   bundle.js:19765
ReactFireMixin.componentWillMount.firebaseRefs  @   bundle.js:19766
(anonymous function)    @   bundle.js:19774
__webpack_require__ @   bundle.js:20
(anonymous function)    @   bundle.js:57
__webpack_require__ @   bundle.js:20
(anonymous function)    @   bundle.js:40
(anonymous function)    @   bundle.js:43
```

Here is my code:

```
import react from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import reactfire from 'reactfire';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class app extends react.component {
    render() {
        return <h1>
            hello bitches!
        </h1>
    }
}
var element = react.createelement(app, {});
render(element, document.queryselector('.app'));
```

Here is my webpack config, not sure if it is required, but added anyway.

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./app/components/Main.js",
output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules | bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me out :)

Comment: So many errors, first off, you can't write everything in lowercase. Secondly mixins doesnt work in ES6 classes.

Comment: So as a general rule of thumb, should I avoid ES6 while learning React?
And about lowercase, are you talking about the name of the class?
I was getting the same error when it was uppercase.

Comment: According to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins) it is okay to use ES6 classes. Probably you can find a replacement for mixins.